# How can I create temporary files in the spark temporary directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to create temporary files as part of a spark run.

I'd like to create them in the same directory as the one I configured for spark (`spark.local.dir`), but I can't work out how.

So either I need a way to make temporary files through spark, or I need to find value of `spark.local.dir` on the workers, and use that.

Comment: what temp files are you trying to create?  spark.local.dir is meant for application specific data to be stored such as cached RDD, intermediate shuffling data,worker logs etc. are you trying to store any of this or ??

Comment: I want to run an external program on each RDD partition, so the flow is:

`RDD Partition -> write to disk -> call program -> read results back into partition`

By default the files are created in /tmp, but on AWS I set spark to use /mnt. I'd like to just have one config option, rather than two, so I want to use the value spark uses.